# populating a google visualization table with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-api, google-visualization

I am trying to load some data from my web api into a google table.

So my web api returns the correct data. It returns 2 columns of data, Name (string) & Score (double).

I want to populate the google table with this data but can't quite see how to do it. I also want to specify the column Names and types prior to adding the data.

Below is my attempt so far. Any help would be great.

I have included at the very bottom a working example of loading a table however the data is hard coded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>QES</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


 <div id="tableScore"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

        function DrawTable() {

            var options = { title: 'Top Scores', showRowNumber: true, width: '75%', height: '75%' };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/Score',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.ajax({

                        var arrValues = {['Name', 'Score']};

                        $.each(data, function(){
                           arrValues.push(data.Name, data.Score);
                        });
                }
            });

            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tableScore'));
            table.draw(arrValues, options);
        };
      });
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

**static data version which works**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Score');

    data.addRows([
      ['Tom',  2.5],
      ['Jack', 8.5]
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tblScore'));

    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '75%', height: '75%'});
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think `var arrValues = {['Name', 'Score']};` should be an array of arrays not an object of arrays. `var arrValues = [['Name', 'Score']]`;

Comment: I put that in but the intellisense is red saying 'expected :'

Comment: In the second example, the data of the cells is brought in by `data.addColumn()` and `data.addRow()` Note that `addRow()` is passing arrays from an array of arrays.